# Prevent Renaming file in SharePoint

Tags: permissions, rename, save

My question is simple, but i'm sure the answer could be complicated. Looking for your thoughts/resolutions:

Q:  I have a new 'Server-Side' document in Sharepoint, and I want to grant people the abilitiy to edit it, but prevent people from saving/uploading it back with a new-file name. How can I do this? To be clear, I'd like people to make changes to the same file only, and not change the name as future changes are made.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Item updating event receiver to your list. In that you can add your business logic to avoid renaming the file.

For more on event receivers:

http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-theory/

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/02/event-receivers-in-sharepoint/